# How to Print Document Library Item?

Tags: document-library, document, printing

Document Library having Number of document items. how to create feature for print item in document library.

Answer (score 1):

its Not Possible For sharepoint 2010 OOB Solution.
you Develop the Custom code .

Comment: please share code if any one have very need Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The method is quite simple.

1) Open the document in a new window
2) When the window is opened use activeX or another method to send that window to print

For 1)
1) Document library.

2) Settings > Document Library settings

3) Advanced settings

4) Check "Browser-enabled Documents"

5) Click OK

6) [Create a new control for the ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606.aspx) < (Start here) and make it open the document in the window (Same as the existing control), but then execute the code for 2)

For 2)
1) Javascript example document..print()

2) Use a activeX control (Plenty around)

Not a short process to complete this, but not all to hard either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hugh Wood. I have tried 2nd option "Use ActiveX control" but facing problem refer [This Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67798/how-to-open-file-in-adobe-reader-using-command-line-without-checkout-from-javasc)

:: Can you please explain more about the 1st example "Javascript example"?
Thanks.